# How to get domain's resolved IP address when using node.js request module?

Tags: node.js, request

I'm using node.js request module and I want to get the resolved IP address without using the `dns` module.

E.g.

```
var request = require('request');

request("http://example.com", function(e, r, body) {
  // how do I get example.com IP address here?
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently the `response.connection.remoteAddress` answer posted elsewhere was true, but the value was set to undefined when execution reached response handler. To work around this, I added an extra event listener to save the value:

```
request("http://example.com", function(e, r, body) {
  console.log("doesn't work", r.connection.remoteAddress);
  console.log('does work', r.remoteIP);
}).on('response', function(res) {
  res.remoteIP = res.connection.remoteAddress;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if things have changed since you posted your answer, but in case anyone else ran across this thread, the following worked fine...

```
const request = require('request');

request("http://example.com", (e, r, body) => {
    console.log(r.connection.remoteAddress)
})
```

The output was: `93.184.216.34`

I didn't have to add an event listener.

Comment: returns undefined for me.